# How to add index.php in the magento url?

Tags: magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7, Suddenly my site start giving me the 404 not found error message for each link. when I add index.php followed by website url its working fine. For example: url xyz.com/index.php/abc.html is working fine but xyz.com/abc.html is not working. So I just want to know how can I add index.php for each link in magento ? please anyone help !

Answer (score 4):

```
Go to admin url of your site.

Next go to System->configuration->web->Search Engines Optimization
Then set 'Use Web Server Rewrites' value to 'No'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change one option value from dropdown in admin.

```
system->configuration->web->search engine optimization change its value to **yes**.
```

Comment: already its value was Yes, After changing its value to No its working fine now. May I know what it is actually "Use Web Server Rewrites" ?  and thanks for suggesting me !!

Comment: you can use this feature to create a more descriptive URL, making it easier for search engines to find your pages like category page, product page etc.

Comment: ok, means when its value will be Yes it will be more descriptive and useful for seo. But in my case it always redirecting me to 404 not found page. So how should I manage this what should I do ?

Comment: You need mod_rewrite enabled on your server. http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-url-rewrites/